# Is there a term for using a word twice in a row, but in a grammatically-appropriate way?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, repetition

For example: "I could tell he had had a great time at the circus."

If you're not repeating the word for emphasis, is there a term for the sequential usage, other than "coincidence"?

Comment: That one is just the [past perfect](http://www.englishtenseswithcartoons.com/tenses/past_perfect). But there are [eleven hads here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_while_John_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_a_better_effect_on_the_teacher), and even Wikipedia doesn't have a name for it. It's certainly not "coincidence" though. I'd call it "contrivance".

Comment: Do you have any more examples other than "had had"?

Comment: @Hugo something like "She didn't know *that that* dog was dangerous" would fit, it seems.

Comment: Is 'isisism' an accepted term yet?

Comment: @FumbleFingers it is perfectly possible to construct an arbitrarily long repetition with valid English. Consider a sign about a store that said "Smith, and, Jones." I write: "There is no comma between Smith and and and and and Jones." But then you question my punctuation and ask: "Isn't there a comma between Smith and and and and and and and and and and and and and and and and and and and and and Jones?" And I can reciprocate by questioning your punctuation. Insanity ensues. And, yes, I think *contrivance* would be the mot juste.

Comment: @Fraser Orr: Argghhh! Trying to decode that one is the lexical / semantic equivalent of an [ear worm!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earworm) As soon as you think you've parsed it at one level, you're tempted to nest it and try again. Repeating ad infinitum or ad nauseum, depending which comes first!

Comment: @onomatomaniak: I don't think that *that that* really means anything different to *that* (in *that* example, as opposed to *this* one! :)

Comment: There's repetition for emphasis, and there's repetition by quoting (the "and and and..." example). I assume you're asking about grammatical acceptable repetition? 'had had' for past perfect, and 'that that' for e relative clause introduction followed by a pronoun are what you're interested in?

Comment: Another example: Never never means never in affairs of the heart.

Comment: They would be a subset of what are known as "dittograms".

Answer (score 1):

Tautonym, like Vulpes Vulpes, for red fox?

Answer (score 0):

EDITED

You might call this a *homonymic* phrase (or compound).

Since homonyms are words that sound the same (or are spelled the same) this might be a proper term do describe a phrase, or a part of a phrase, that includes them.

Reading through the [closest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo) article to the subject, that I could find in wikipedia did not reveal any specific terms that would cover this scenario.

Comment: I down voted because you said it was epizeuxis, and then you corrected yourself and said that it wasn't (because the author said it was a grammatical structure not for emphasis.) I'd be happy to reverse if you edit to correct.

Comment: @FraserOrr, I was not clear - in rhetoric consecutively repeating the words is called epizeuxis. However, that is really a sidenote and not related to what OP asks, so I removed it.

Comment: fair enough, I reversed my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of contrived sentences allowing anything up to an infinite number of repetitions, but no-one has actually given an example where repeating a word serves to emphasise anything. So how about...

> Me: I can see the appeal of Polanski's films if you're a paedophile.
>
> You: I like Polanski's films, but I'm not a paedophile!
>
> Me: I didn't mean *you you*. I mean *if someone else was a paedophile*.

Okay, maybe not the best example. But I do think it conveys emphasis.

Answer (score 0):

Contrastive focus reduplication. " I like you, but I don't (like) like you."

Comment: That's certainly one good example of the phenomenon (and you also give a nice example), but _contrastive focus reduplication_ (eg '_coffee_ coffee' has been specifically covered here elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be termed a composite phrase? The French or Latin origin means "to put together". Composite implies joining. It's the first word that came to mind when reading a news article tonight and noticing unnecessary duplication of the word "that".

Answer (score -1):

You can occasionally repeat a word for emphasis, usually in speech; for example:

> She looked over her shoulder and said: 'He's very, very good ...'

But you can't repeat adjectives for emphasis; for example:

> a red, red cloth

Is incorrect; whilst

> a very red cloth

is fine. However, it is doable in certain languages, for examlle - Bengali; the forner translates as

> lal (red), lal (red) kapor (cloth)

It's where the double not for emphases not comes from. I don't know the grammatical term that describes this, but there is likely to be one.

Comment: Better not tell Robert Burns that he couldn't write about his love being like a red, red rose.