# Name for the repetition evident in "How much larger should it be to be secure?"

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

I'm editing a post that has the sentence:

> How much larger should it be to be secure?

I've come across other situations where there are repetitions in a sentence (such as `that that`) and am hoping for a word to describe this occurrence and a generalized approach to rethink it so the sentence becomes clearer.

Comment: Have you looked here for your answer yet?  Though it isn't complete it may benefit you and other visitors.

http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46756/is-there-a-term-for-using-a-word-twice-in-a-row-but-in-a-grammatically-appropri

Comment: There is nothing unclear about the sentence.

Comment: You could describe it as "proper grammar".